# How to alter TYPE using the Cassandra Java Driver SchemaBuilder?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I found it is possible add a column to a user defined type on Cassandra using CQL (http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlRefAlterType.html), but how can i do it using Java core driver?

I'm using 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.6' and 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-mapping:2.1.6'

To create a type, i did with this code using the method "createType" on SchemaBuilder. But it doesn't have a method "alterType" or something like this.

May somebody has a solution?

Thanks,
Luiz

Comment: I believe you are looking for alterTable().alterColumn() -->  https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/commit/5a8019f67ae9c938477e49a2d6aea7d7aff92de9#diff-7b447659109a8bb4fc0dee0f887db173R49

Comment: No. I don't want alter a table, i wanna alter a type.
I have a previously created type, and i want to add a new field to this type.

it's like `ALTER TYPE my_type ADD my_column text;`

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?